# Is there a way to enable Developer tools on MS Teams for iOS?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am searching for a method to activate developer tools, specifically to generate console logs for the actions taken within the MS Teams iOS app.

Although I have reviewed Microsoft's official documentation on how to enable this feature, which can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools, it appears that it does not include instructions for enabling this functionality on iOS.

I have tried enabling `About > Developer preview` as you would do for Desktop and Android, and can't find an option for Dev tools on iOS.
[About page MS Teams app iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipI6f.png)

And then tried using the safari develop option to inspect on iPhone [Safari develop - no inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIXA4.png)

Tried inspecting as said above because I do know that to load apps in MS Teams, it uses Mobile Safari (Webkit), so I would expect to inspect as I do for safari on iOS, but I know I'm missing something here [Mobile safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtQfg.png)

I would expect some interface that would allow me to look at logs from what is going on in MS Teams app on iOS, I have been testing an app in MS Teams and can't have more information to resolve some issues that arise on MS Teams app on iOS because there is no logs to see.

Do you know what else can I try? Is there an option? Thanks :D

Comment: Currently DevTools feature is available only for Desktop and Android. You can suggest this feature at [Microsoft Teams Feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).